# Display a text letter by letter in Android / Runnables are too slow

Tags: java, android, runnable

I searched but i didn't found an answer, so I hope somebody can help me. I want to write a text letter by letter like `H` to `He` and then to `Hel` and so on. I did this already with Runnables:

```
private void text001(final String finishedText) {
    ...
    ...
    final String text = getResources().getString(R.string.first_start_001);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            professorText.setText(finishedText + text.charAt(finishedText.length()));
            String finishedTextExtra = finishedText + text.charAt(finishedText.length());
            text001(finishedTextExtra);
            Log.i("actual Text Speed", textSpeed + "");
        }
    }, textSpeed);
    ...
    ...
}
```

But it seems like the Runnables are too slow. If I set the textSpeed to 50ms the text appears not faster than if I set the textSpeed to 100ms. I thought maybe i have to do this completely different, but i found no other way. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Just tried your code. It works, speed changes dependent of `textSpeed` value. Could you post more code?

Comment: My problem isn't that it not works, the problem is that i cant see differences between `textSpeed` 100ms and 50ms. And sometimes 100ms is faster and sometimes slower.